Would the following table containing two foreign keys also be the primary key for that table?
Can a single table which has two foreign keys also be considered the primary key (taken together) of that table? I'm adding a screenshot from the Invitation to Computer Science 6th edition textbook I'm reading that shows the InsurancePolicies table with two foreign keys, but my question is, are these two foreign keys also considered the primary key for that table? The author in textbook does not explicitly state this.
I think the answer is yes but I'm not sure and I couldn't locate a concrete answer so hopefully someone can provide an easy to understand answer.

This is the closest answer I could find (here) on SO so my second question would be would by default the two foreign keys be considered the primary key, too?

Yes, a table can have 2 or more foreign keys that together form a composite primary key.
Composite keys need to be explicitly declared, even when they consist of foreign keys.
CREATE TABLE InsurancePolicies (
    EmployeeID INTEGER,
    PlanType VARCHAR(50),
    DateIssue DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID, PlanType),
    FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PlanType) REFERENCES InsurancePlans(PlanType)
);

Without explicit declaration you would not enforce uniqueness and potentially allow duplicate pairs of (EmployeeID, PlanType).

A KEY is a combination of 1 or more columns with a special meaning. Such meaning could be an index (to speed up searches by said columns), a unique (ensuring that no two records can exist in the table with the same value combination for the columns that are part of the key), foreign key (a combination of columns that together represent a reference to another table's primary key) and primary key, which can also be composite.
Now that you understand that any key is of the form of (c1, c2, ..., cn) where c1 ... cn are columns, this should clarify that primary keys as well as other keys have no limitation on the number of columns that comprise it.
Now, let's suppose that you have a column C that is factually unique in the table it's part of. This field will not become a key, not unique, nor primary key, nor anything else unless it is specified as such, even though it could be a unique or a primary key alike.
A combination of columns that together are unique are candidate keys and can be used as primary keys.
In your InsurancePolicies table EmployeeID is a foreign key referencing Employees and InsurancePlans is referenced by the foreign key called PlanType.
The diagram does not mention them as primary keys of (EmployeeID and PlanType) and, unless the dark orange color means primary key (which I am not convinced of), you have no reason to think they are together a primary key.
It's not even guaranteed to have this as a possibility. What if an employee issued an insurance plan and paid for it for a few months, then switched to another plan, but later on switched back to the original plan he was part of?
Let's assume that Employee1 issued for InsurancePlan1 on January 1st 2000 and have been paying for it until January 1st 2010 when Employee1 instead of InsurancePlan1 issued for InsurancePlan2. And then, in January 1st 2020, Employee1 issued for InsurancePlan1 again.
This means that Employee1 has two different DateIssued for InsurancePlan1, which, in the current construct can only be represented in two different records in the InsurancePolicies table whose EmployeeID and PlanType matches, defeating the purpose of using these two fields together as a primary key.
If such scenarios are impossible for a reason in your project, then you will be able to use this combination as a primary key, but even if such a scenario is impossible now, it may become possible later on as your project evolves.
So, as Boyce-Codd proposed in BCNF (Boyce-Codd Normal Form), it's a further step in database normalization to avoid such composite primary keys, even though they are perfectly legal, since over time you may end up having to refactor large databases if they turn out to be duplicatable after all. Instead, this Normal Form proposes to have an atomic, 1-dimensional key in every table, so you would have a new ID field in InsurancePolicies which will be the primary key and this will be a bullet-proof solution from the perspective of your foreign keys, because, if it turns out that the same employee for whatever reason may have the same insurance plan more than once (two cars insured with the same plan for example), then your schema will still fulfill the purpose.
As about whether (EmployeeID, PlanType) is a primary key right now, check the table definition and see how exactly the table is defined and whether these two fields act together as the primary key.

The combination of the 2 FK-keys is a so-called "composite primary key" and as a such can be a primary key. A composite key in an SQL table is a primary key that consists of two or more columns combined to uniquely identify a record in the table. This is used when a single column cannot uniquely identify a row, but a combination of columns can.

Just a one quick clarification when the InsurancePolicies table was created was it necessary to declare explicitly the two attributes EmployeeID and PlanType as primary keys or is it by the mere declaring of these two attributes as foreign keys does these two keys become also become composite primary keys by default ?

The two foreign keys are a composite primary key if and only if they are specified to be so. They may be a candidate key together if they are guaranteed to be unique, but even that is doubtful, imagine the same employee having two cars insuring both using the same plan. In that case the combination of the two fields is not unique and they cannot be used as a primary key. A composite key is not necessarily a primary key, you can have composite index keys, unique keys or foreign keys alike. A single column can always used to be a primary key, nobody can prevent you from adding an ID field.
